# Proving A=RU where R is nonnegative self-adjoint mapping and U is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, isometry, unitary-matrices

I'm trying to following proof of this.

$A$ which is linear mapping of complex Euclidean space into itself.

Then $A$ can be factorized by

$A=RU$ where $R$ is nonnegative self-adjoint mapping, and $U$ is unitary.

I already did when $A$ is invertible, but I'm stuck with not invertible case.

If $A$ is not invertible,

Scalar product $(AA^*x,x)=(A^*x,A^*x) \geq 0$. Thus, $AA^*$ is nonnegative.

By Theorem, $AA^*$ has unique nonnegative self-adjoint square root. Denote it $R$.

$\parallel Rx \parallel^2=(Rx,Rx)=(R^2x,x)=(AA^*x,x)=(A^*x,A^*x)=\parallel A^*x\parallel^2$

Suppose $Rx=Ry$.

Then $\parallel R(x-y)\parallel=0$. Thus, $\parallel A^*(x-y)\parallel=0$. Therefore, $A^*x=A^*y$

---Until this, I can easily follow. But here, I cannot follow.---

This shows that for any $u$ in the range of $R$, $u=Rx$, we can define $Vu$ as $A^*x$

According to upper equation, which is

$\parallel Rx \parallel^2=(Rx,Rx)=(R^2x,x)=(AA^*x,x)=(A^*x,A^*x)=\parallel A^*x\parallel^2$,

$V$ is an isometry.

---Here, I can't understand why $V$ is an isometry from that equation.

Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V$ is an isometry because it maps $Rx$ to $A^*x$, and by your "upper equation", $\|Rx\|=\|A^*x\|$. By the way, this only gives $V$ as an isometry from $\operatorname{ran}R$ to $\operatorname{ran}A^*$. You now have to extend it to an isometry on the whole space.

You're looking at the polar decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_theory#Polar_decomposition

If you have access to Axler's book ("Linear Algebra Done Right"), he has a good exposition in 7.D (p.234).

Comment: Oh if we let $Rx_1=u_1, A^*x_1=v_1$, $Rx_2=u_2, A^*x_2=v_2$ than $\parallel V(u_1-u_2)\parallel = \parallel v_1-v_2\parallel=\parallel u_1-u_2\parallel$ So it preserves distance? Am I right?

Comment: I figure out that extend isometry is one another big problem to me...
The book just say ; therefore it can be extended to the whole space as a unitary mapping.. How can I do this?

Comment: For your first question, it's even simpler than that: if $V$ preserves norms, then it preserves distances. And $\|V(Rx)\| = \|A^*x\| = \|Rx\|$, so it preserves norms. For your other question, you can define $V$ to act like the identity on the complementary part of the vector space.

Comment: But then, for $x=u+v$, where $u=Ra$ for some $a$, $(u,v)=0$
Since $Vu=A^*a$ and $Vv=v$
$\parallel V(u+v)\parallel = \parallel A^*a+v\parallel$
So we have to show that $(A^*a,v)=0$